# Why are all vectors with exactly one nonzero component not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In order for a set of vectors to be part of a subspace there can't be any redundant vectors included in the set, i.e the set should contain only the minimum amount of vectors necessary which can be scaled and combined in different ways to span the entire subspace. Correct?

Might it be the case then that if my set includes ALL vectors with exactly one nonzero component that there will clearly be redundancy in my set?

The zero vector is included and the set is both closed under scalar multiplication and addition so I don't see any other explanation.

Comment: Closed under addition, you said? (1,0,0) + (0,0,1) = ?

Comment: It''s hard to be certain whether the first sentence is correct since it's very unclear what it means. But it sounds like  you're confusing "part of a subspace" with "basis for a subspace"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set is not closed under addition. Consider the vectors $\vec{v} = (1,0,0)$ and $\vec{w} = (0,1,0)$. The sum is $\vec{v}+\vec{w} = (1,1,0)$, i.e. a vector with **two** nonzero components.

Also I don't think the zero vector is included, since it has exactly zero nonzero components.